GMAIL addon on IOS recipients subjects missing metadata
I have an Appscript plugin for GMAIL, in the manifest it says this:
"composeTrigger": {
  "draftAccess": "METADATA",
  "selectActions": [
    {
      "text": "Send",
      "runFunction": "FuncionDatos"
    }
  ]
},

The function is this:
function FuncionDatos(e) {
  let Borrador = e.draftMetadata;  
  
  let Para = Borrador.toRecipients.join(";");
  let Asunto = Borrador.subject.toString();

  return true;
}

Everything works OK on Web and Android, but in the IOS GMAIL app almost always in toRecipients, subject,... it does not collect the data. Sometimes, but very rarely, it collects the data correctly. I think the problem is synchronization, but I haven't solved the problem.
The intention is to collect data as it does on the Web and Android.
I've tried a setInteval (doesn't work in apsscript on IOS) a Utilities.sleep() (Neither)...
